# What is the proper way to synchronously update graph properties and topology within a GTK loop in graph-tool?

Tags: python, graph, gtk, graph-tool

I'm trying to find the neatest way to make an animation similar to [this one](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/demos/animation/animation.html#dynamic-layout), with the difference that I need to update the graph topology and the vertices' properties synchronously (it's a graph analog of the game of life). I have been doing so far by simply constructing a graph sequence by copying the graph on the *(i-1)*-th iteration, computing alterations based on the original graph, and returning the updated copy.

As it seems to me, the problem with this approach is that when using `GraphWindow`, like in the linked example, I need to modify the graph in-place, instead of making copies. So the best I could do was to iterate twice over the graph, at each call of the `update_state` function. The first iteration is to compute the new states, the second to assign them. A batch assignment would work for properties with scalar values, but I couldn't manage to do it for properties with string values.

Summing it up, I want to, at each call of `update_state`, update synchronously two properties, a scalar one, corresponding to the state of a vertex, `vp.state`, and a string-valued one, corresponding to its color, `vp.color`;

This is an excerpt of the [full code](https://gist.github.com/izzortsi/9de19360dd1e249f5f60cb21f8366f7f) (the `update_state` function -- which I named `run_simulation`)

```python
def run_simulation():

    global count, g
    
    to_remove = []
    alterations = []
    r = 0
    

    for v in g.get_vertices():
        if len(g.get_all_edges(v)) == 0:
            print(r)
            r+=1
            to_remove.append(v)
        else:
            Nv = g.get_all_neighbors(v)
            sum_nbstates = sum([g.vp.state[u] for u in Nv])
            nb_size = len(Nv)
            acoef = sum_nbstates / nb_size
    
            if g.vp.state[v] == 1:
                if 2 / nb_size <= acoef <= 3 / nb_size:
                    state = 1
                    color = "white"
                else:
                    state = 0
                    color = "black"

            elif g.vp.state[v] == 0:
                # if (acoef == 3/nb_size):
                if 2 / nb_size <= acoef <= 4 / nb_size:
                    state = 1
                    color = "white"
                else:
                    state = 0
                    color = "black"
            
            alterations.append([v, state, color])
            states.append(state)
            colors.append(color)

    ###some checks
    #print(vertices)
    diff = len(to_remove)
    if diff >= 1:
        print(f"diff {diff}, count {count}") #this eventually results in something ≠ 0, I still haven't find out why 
    ###
        
    for (v, new_state, new_color) in alterations:
        g.vp.state[v] = new_state
        g.vp.color[v] = new_color


    gt.sfdp_layout(
        g, pos=g.vp.pos, eweight=g.ep.weight, max_iter=1, init_step=0.01, K=0.5
         )

    g.remove_vertex(to_remove) 

    count += 1

    win.graph.regenerate_surface()
    win.graph.queue_draw()
    
    if OFFSCREEN:
        pixbuf = win.get_pixbuf()
        pixbuf.savev(r'./frames/graphol%06d.png' % count, 'png', [], [])

    if count >= max_count:
        sys.exit(0)

    return True
```